# How to take previous all year or data from array in laravel?

Tags: laravel

This is my all static financial year in array i have created in helper.php.There are two function like currentFinancialYear and lastFinancialYear where my current financial year is now "2020/21".and i will get 2019/20 from last financial Year.What i should do now if i need both previous year like 2018/19 and 2019/20 if my current financial year is 2020/21. or What i do now if my current financial year ii 2021/2022 and i need previous all 3 year

```
//This is my all Financial year
function getAllFinancialYears()
{
    return array(
        '2018/19' => array(
            'year' => '2018/19',
             'from' => '07/16/2018',
            'to' => '07/15/2019'
        ),
        '2019/20' => array(
            'year' => '2019/20',
            'from' => '07/16/2019',
            'to' => '07/15/2020'
        ),
        '2020/21' => array(
            'year' => '2020/21',
            'from' => '07/16/2020',
            'to' => '07/15/2021'
        ),
        '2021/22' => array(
            'year' => '2021/22',
             'from' => '07/16/2021',
            'to' => '07/15/2022'
        ),
        '2022/23' => array(
            'year' => '2022/23',
            'from' => '07/16/2022',
            'to' => '07/15/2023'
        ),
    );
}
//This is function for currentFinancialYear
function currentFinancialYear() {
    return '2020/21';
}
This is my Last Financial year of CurrentFinanicail year 
function lastFinancialYear($y = false) {
    if ($y) {
        $year = $y;
    } else {
        $year = currentFinancialYear();
    }

    $all_years = getAllFinancialYears();

    while(key($all_years) !== null && key($all_years) !== $year) next($all_years);

    $prev_key = prev($all_years);

    return $prev_key['year'] ?? '';
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixing your currentFinancialYear function**

I would use carbon to return whichever todays date falls under

you may need to parse the from and to dates using carbon but you should get the idea

```
function currentFinancialYear() {
    $years = $this->getAllFinancialYears();
    foreach($years as $year => $ranges) {
        if (\Carbon\Carbon::now()->between($ranges['from'],$ranges['to'])){
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

For the next one i would change the function slightly. I havent tested this but hopefully if you were to pass 0 it would get the current year, pass 1 then current year and last year, pass 2 then current and the previous two years etc:

```
function getPreviousFinancialYears($y = 0) {
    $years = $years = $this->getAllFinancialYears();
    $all_years = [];
    
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $i; $x++) {
        foreach($years as $year => $ranges) {
            if (\Carbon\Carbon::now()->subYear($x)->between($ranges['from'],$ranges['to'])){
                array_push($all_years, $key);
            }
        }
    }

    return $all_years;
   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i think i cannot use Carbon::now because i made function both for Nepali and English.Suppose "2020/21" mean Nepali "2077". So What can do is create currentFinancialYear() but i donot know how to get previous from currenFinancailYear.

Comment: i am just struck like 3 days and i tried different ways but cannot resolve.
I cannot modified function also because this app system is already in production

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Laravels collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections)

```php
// Create a collection
$stats = collect([
    '2018/19' => array(
        'year' => '2018/19',
         'from' => '07/16/2018',
        'to' => '07/15/2019'
    ),
    '2019/20' => array(
        'year' => '2019/20',
        'from' => '07/16/2019',
        'to' => '07/15/2020'
    ),
    '2020/21' => array(
        'year' => '2020/21',
        'from' => '07/16/2020',
        'to' => '07/15/2021'
    ),
    '2021/22' => array(
        'year' => '2021/22',
         'from' => '07/16/2021',
        'to' => '07/15/2022'
    ),
    '2022/23' => array(
        'year' => '2022/23',
        'from' => '07/16/2022',
        'to' => '07/15/2023'
    ),
]);


$currentYear = '2020/21';

// Get the stats from this year
$currentYearsStats = $stats->get(currentYear);
```

#### Improvement using single years & Carbon

If you would single years in your stats *and* would use the fantastic date library [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) then you don't need to hardcode the years (except in your stats, of course):

```php
$stats = collect([
    '2018' => array(
        // ...
    ),
    '2019' => array(
        // ...
    ),
    '2020' => array(
        //...
    ),
    '2021' => array(
        //...
    ),
    '2021' => array(
        //...
    ),
    '2022' => array(
        //...
    ),

]);
```

then you would also be able to do magic like this

```php
// This year, 2021
$currentYearsStats = $stats->get(Carbon::now()->year);

// Last year, 2020
$lastYearsStats = $stats->get(Carbon::now()->subYear()->year);

// Next year, 2022
$nextYearsStats = $stats->get(Carbon::now()->addYear()->year);
```

Comment: Actually this "'2019/20'" mean for both English and Nepali date also.so i made function likewise.So i made function for getCurrentFinancialYear.I think  i cannot use Carbon::now.But i can use is that getCurrentFinancialYear Function "2019/20" and get all previous array.